# Верно ли решена задача? Что можно улучшить?

Tags: javascript

Создайте инпут, в который пользователь вводит дату своего рождения в формате '2014-12-31' (с конкретным годом). По потери фокуса выведите под инпутом сколько дней осталось до его дня рождения. Воспользуйтесь методом Date.parse.

На имена переменных и обработчик в атрибуте можно не обращать внимание.

```js
function gdate(elem) {
 var inputValue = elem.value;
 var date = new Date();
 var fromNow = Date.parse(String(date.getFullYear()) + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
 var fromTarget = Date.parse(inputValue);
 var result = (fromTarget - fromNow) / (1000 * 60 *60 *24) ;

 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Math.round(result);
}
```

```css
input {
 width: 250px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите дату в формате 2014-12-31" onblur="gdate(this)">
 <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Отсутствие валидации меня тоже не беспокоит.

Comment: `fromTarget - fromNow` - нужно наоборот - `fromNow - fromTarget`

Comment: @Alex чет я сильно сомневаюсь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Получим элемент с id="date-input"
document.querySelector('#date-input')
  // Повесим обработчик
  .addEventListener('blur', function() {
    // bd - день рождения
    // Date.parse не обязательна,
    // можно просто new Date(this.value)
    let bd = new Date(Date.parse(this.value))
    // now - дата сейчас
    let now = new Date
    // Обновим год дня рождения на текущий
    bd.setFullYear(+now.getFullYear())
    // Если в этом году уже был день рождения
    if (bd <= now) {
      // Переносим на след. год
      bd.setFullYear(+bd.getFullYear() + 1)
    }
    // Получаем разницу во времени
    let diff = Math.round((+bd - now) / 86400000)
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = diff
  })
```

```css
input {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #222;
  padding: 10px;
  appearance: none;
  webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="date-input" type="text" placeholder="Введите дату в формате 2014-12-31">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: кроме setFullYear есть в датах еще какие-то set? (timeout/interval не в счет). Просто впервые сталкиваюсь с таким методом, надо понять что гуглить.

Comment: @websnap прогуглите документацию JavaScript. В данном случае класса Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date